# How do I access the value of bound control on a non-displayed tab for validation?

Tags: winforms, validation, data-binding, tabcontrol

I have created a dialog which contains 3 tabs.  Controls on Tabs 1 & 2 have validation using the `Validating()` event.  The user will mainly be working on Tabs 1 & 3, never displaying Tab 2 unless necessary.  All controls on Tabs 1 & 2 are bound to a BindingSource object.

From my observation, it appears that the bound controls are not initialized on Tab 2 until the tab is displayed.  As a result, validating for the entire form fails since those controls have no value.  The TextBox.Text value is `""` when `Validating()` is called the first time, and `somevalue` after I view the tab.

I tried to 'pre-initialize' the controls on Tab 2 from the `Load` event (e.g. `TextBox.Value = 'test';`, but found the value was cleared before Validating() was called.

I had thoughts about checking the value from BindingSource.Current, but this particular solution has multiple pitfalls, notably the BindingSource containing an unvalidated value.

What step(s) do I need to take to either:

- initialize the controls before they are displayed
- obtain the proper value (control or BindingSource) for `Validation()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't find any authoritative sources to confirm, it appears that bound controls are not initialized until they are made visible.  I was able to confirm similar behavior on my default displayed tab by hiding a text box.  The control's `.Text` value was `""` until the control was made visible, at which time the value was populated with my expected value.

A [question](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/it-IT/netfxbcl/thread/2a04af52-7eb0-4830-b67f-3343bf46685e) on Microsoft forums further confirmed what I was experiencing:

> This is the way .NET data binding works: the binding is nonfunctional until the control first becomes visible.
>   ...
>   There is no workaround short of making the control visible temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by programmatically changing to the Tab2 and then switching back to Tab1

```
        foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl.TabPages)
        {
            tab.Visible = true;
        }
        tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: It is a solution, but not ideal, due to what I consider an form appearance to the user.  It did however open up a few more doors in my search for an answer to my question.